# Not able to run bloc test as giving expected and actual are not mathcing

Tags: flutter, bloc

Bloc event

```
 FutureOr<void> _onGenerateOtpForForgot(
    _GenerateOtpForForgot event,
    Emitter<AuthNewState> emit,
  ) async {
    try {
      emit(state.copyWith(isBusy: true));
      final OtpResponseModel response = await _repository.generateOtpForForgot(event.body);

      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          isBusy: false,
          notification: _NotifySuccess(
            message: response.data!.message.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e, s) {
      _log.e('Login failed', e, s);
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          isBusy: false,
          notification: _NotifyFailed(
            message:
                e is DioException ? e.response!.data['message'] : e.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

This is state class

```
@Freezed()
class AuthNewState with _$AuthNewState {
  const factory AuthNewState({
    @Default(UIInitial()) UIStatus status,
    AuthNotification? notification,
    @Default([]) List<CountryCodeModel> countryCodes,
    @Default(false) bool isBusy,

  }) = _AuthNewState;
}
```

Test Class

```
void main() {
  final AuthNewRepository repository = MockAuthNewRepository();
  late AuthNewBloc bloc;
  final LogService logService = MockLogService();
  
  late LoginRequestModel body;
  const OtpResponseModel otpResponseModel =
      OtpResponseModel(type: "", count: 1, data: Data());

  setUp(() {
    bloc = AuthNewBloc(
      logService: logService,
      authRepository: repository,
    );
    body = const LoginRequestModel(userName: "");
  });

  group("Generate otp", () {
    blocTest(
      'emit state when success for event [_onGenerateOtpForForgot]',
      setUp: () {
        when(repository.generateOtpForForgot(body)).thenAnswer(
          (_) => Future<OtpResponseModel>.value(
            otpResponseModel,
          ),
        );
      },
      build: () => bloc,
      act: (_) => bloc.add(
        AuthNewEvent.generateOtpForForgot(body),
      ),
      expect: () => [
        isA<AuthNewState>().having(
          (state) => state.isBusy,
          'isBusy',
          true,
        ),
        isA<AuthNewState>()
            .having(
              (state) => state.notification,
              'notification',
              AuthNotification.notifySuccess(message: "message"),
            )
            .having(
              (state) => state.isBusy,
              'isBusy',
              false,
            ),
      ],
    );
  });
}
```

Geting error

```
Expected: [
            <<Instance of 'AuthNewState'> with `isBusy`: <true>>,
            <<Instance of 'AuthNewState'> with `notification`: _$NotifySuccessImpl:<AuthNotification.notifySuccess(message: message, loginResponseModel: null)> and `isBusy`: <false>>
          ]
  Actual: [
            _$AuthNewStateImpl:AuthNewState(status: UIStatus.initial(), notification: null, countryCodes: [], isBusy: true),
            _$AuthNewStateImpl:AuthNewState(status: UIStatus.initial(), notification: AuthNotification.notifySuccess(message: null, loginResponseModel: null), countryCodes: [], isBusy: false)
          ]
   Which: at location [1] is _$AuthNewStateImpl:<AuthNewState(status: UIStatus.initial(), notification: AuthNotification.notifySuccess(message: null, loginResponseModel: null), countryCodes: [], isBusy: false)> which has `notification` with value _$NotifySuccessImpl:<AuthNotification.notifySuccess(message: null, loginResponseModel: null)>
```